# there is an error in build gradle where debug.keystore key is not reading or failed to read the key

Tags: flutter, android-studio, build.gradle, android-keystore

[failed to read the debug.Keystore in android studio flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MffeD.png)

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 64 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
> com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\ADMIN.android\debug.keystore": Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

Comment: You are trying to use a keystore created by a newer Java (probably keytool) on an older Java. **This has been asked and answered repeatedly, see:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67853815/error-while-building-app-bundle-integrity-check-failed-jalgorithm-hmacpbesha2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631927/error-building-aab-flutter-android-integrity-check-failed-java-security-n https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67766268/ioexception-in-java-8-when-reading-pkcs12-keystore-created-with-keytool-from-ope