# What is the reason for "java.io.IOException: Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available"

Tags: java, ssl

I am trying to load a Keystore from the following Java code sample.

```
    private KeyStore getKeyStore(File keyStore, String keyStorePassword) throws IOException {
        KeyStore ks = null;
        String  tlsStoreType = "PKCS12";
        if (keyStore != null && keyStorePassword != null) {
            try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(keyStore)) {
                ks = KeyStore.getInstance(tlsStoreType);
                ks.load(is, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
            } catch (CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException e) {
                throw new IOException(e);
            }
        }
        return ks;
    }
```

But I am getting the exception, "java.io.IOException: Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available". The Java version which I am going to run the above code sample is `openjdk version "11.0.9" 2020-10-20 LTS`.

I used the keytool command to create the keystore,

```
keytool -genkey -keystore server-keystore.jks -alias server_alias \
        -dname "CN=the.server.host.name,OU=whateveryoulike" \
        -keyalg "RSA" -sigalg "SHA1withRSA" -keysize 2048 -validity 365
```

What is the reason for this exception?

Comment: Dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631927/error-building-aab-flutter-android-integrity-check-failed-java-security-n and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71248098/there-is-an-error-in-build-gradle-where-debug-keystore-key-is-not-reading-or-fai

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this exception was, that the Keystore was created in the Java version `openjdk version "17.0.9" 2023-10-17` and is being used in the version `openjdk version "11.0.9" 2020-10-20 LTS`. HmacPBESHA256 is a new algorithm introduced in later versions of JDK. So generating the Keystore in the same Java version solved the issue.